# Complicated Excel Formula

Tags: excel, vba

I'm hoping that this is possible and that this community can help.

I've got cell D19 that I need to calculate. This calculation will be based on the following:

- Cell D18 contains an otherwise calculated formula that outputs a percentage.
- Cell G8 contains a 4 digit code. That cell matches **some or all** of the text contained in a matrix of cells on a different worksheet -- that matrix includes cells B5:B143.
- On that different worksheet, columns BN through BU contain percentage figures that are the ultimate output goal that needs to end up in cell D19. BN4 through BU4 contain percentages starting from 5% and increasing in increments of 5% until reaching 40%. Beneath each column header, there is a column full of different percentages.
- I need the entry in cell G8 to inform D19, based on what is included in cell D18 (which is the percentage figure mentioned in the first bullet point, above) being rounded down to the nearest 5%, which will activate a lookup in the BN through BU matrix and populate D19 with a percentage figure.

For example, D18 says 21.6%. G8 says S700. Somewhere in B5:B143 there is the text S700, and in column BQ (with a heading of "20%") in cell BQ54, it says 2.72%. I want the 2.72% to show up in cell D19.

Sorry for the complicated question! I hope someone can help!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Could you break up the different functions into columns, for example, using an =IF function to read G8 and see if matches the matrix? (Functions of the form =IF(SEARCH("3",G8),TRUE,FALSE) would return TRUE if there were a 3 in G8, FALSE otherwise.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=INDEX(differentworksheet!BN4:BU143,MATCH("*"&G8&"*",differentworksheet!B4:B143,0),MATCH(D18,differentworksheet!BN4:BU4,1))
```

Replace differentworksheet with your worksheets name.